# Sql Developer: Enter Substitution Variable

Tags: plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am getting an annoying  pop-up,  Asking  for Entering Substituon Variable
    in Oracle Sql   Developer 4.0.
            I am getting it when i am trying to Compile a Stored Procedure. 
I can't attach Stored Procedure here due to privacy reasons.  If anyone can guess what can be the problem, Please suggest.

Comment: Well, does the procedure code (or anything else in the script if you're running multiple things together) contain a substitution variable, something starting with an ampersand (`&`)? The pop-up usually tells you the name of the variable it's looking for, which might help narrow it down. Long-shot maybe, but are you using `&&` instead of `AND` somewhere? Really going to be difficult to be more helpful without seeing the code unfortunately. Perhaps you can create a dummy procedure that has the same behaviour and post that.

Comment: Following up on @AlexPoole's comment - the `&` might be anywhere, including in a comment. I've been burned more than once by ampersands in comments - this will compile just fine from PL/SQL Developer, but our migration procedure uses SQL*Plus to do the compile...  :-(

Comment: @AlexPoole yes your idea is working.

Answer (score 3):

Alex is indeed right, but those characters might be in there on purpose. It that's the case you can try to put "SET DEFINE OFF" above your code and then try to compile it.